# How to query Intents handled for my own app in Android

Tags: android

Is there a way to distinguish between background service launches vs. Launch Intents for UI on Android?

In my app in the Application I need to determine whether to launch a different Activity if the app is launched by the user and we are suppose to show UI vs. the application being created i.e. background push

I know that this can be done by doing ActivityManager.getAppTasks(), however for pre-lollipop this requires the permission `GET_TASKS` which is something we can't do with our app.

Is there any way for us to get all the Intents handled by my app so that I can query whether the intent has `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`

Comment: Why not simply analyze the content of the `Intent` that launched your app? See [`Activity.getIntent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent()).

Comment: The problem is that there are many activities so i would have to modify the base activity to get the Intent. Is there anyway we can do this via the Application?